# Spotfire Sum over multiple levels

Tags: analytics, tibco, spotfire

I have an expense file that includes a separate record for each attendee but repeats the total expense amount.

```
Employee    Report ID   Transaction Date    Vendor           City/Location  Expense Type    Approved Amount Attendee Name
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           UNITED AIRLINES  NYC            Airfare         317.1           Jane smith
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           UNITED AIRLINES  NYC            Airfare         317.1           jack smith
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           UNITED AIRLINES  NYC            Airfare         317.1           tom white
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           Bar and Grill    NYC            Dinner          94.74           kelly thompson
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           Bar and Grill    NYC            Dinner          94.74           joan ellen
John Smith  A           4/20/2016           Bar and Grill    NYC            Dinner          94.74           albert coals
```

I need to sum the total of the expenses by city without duplicating the expense amount. I have tried the following custom expression while doing a cross table on city:

```
Sum(max([Approved Amount]) over (Intersect([Transaction Date],[Vendor])))
```

But this has resulted in

```
City  Amount
NYC   1235.52
```

I am looking for a result like

```
City  Amount
NYC   411.84
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a line item ID or some way to uniquely identify an expense record?

Comment: The record doesn't have a unique identifier.

Comment: would there ever be a fully duplicate row? i.e. same attendee for same amount and city and vendor and employee,etc...?

Comment: There should not ever be a completely duplicated row, it is possible from a data entry error aspect though.

Comment: Well if there is a possibility then there is no way to assign a unique key and thus any aggregation on a "group" could produce invalid results (or undesired) without first cleansing the data before you bring it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cookiemnstr247 - Please test the below solution and let me know if it works.

**Step 1:** Inserted calculated column 'Rank'

```
Rank([Approved Amount],"desc",[Employee],[Transaction Date],[City/Location],[Vendor],"ties.method=first")
```

**Step 2:** Inserted another calculated column 'sumvalue'

```
If([Rank]=1,[Approved Amount],0)
```

**Step 3:** Created a cross table as shown in the screen shot below

[image]

I have tested this solution with different scenarios and it seems to be stable.

*Note: Employee, Transaction date, city/Location and Vendor are only used for grouping in this case. If you would like add more columns to grouping, please add those to rank column*

Comment: What if there is a duplicate row?

Comment: We will have to review the data and remove any duplicates beforehand, but otherwise this seemed to deliver the results required. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't know until it's too late @cookiemnstr247

Answer (score 0):

I THINK this will work, though I admit I'm having a bit of trouble testing:

```
Sum(Max([Approved Amount]) OVER (Intersect(All([Axis.Rows]),[Vendor])) * (If(RankReal([Approved Amount],[Vendor],"ties.method=first")>1,0,1)))
```